# How can I add a custom page to Shopify without the /pages/ URL?

Tags: shopify

I want `domain.com/custompage`, but the built in functionality puts all pages inside a /pages/ directory so the URL comes out `domain.com/pages/custompage` which I don't want.

I found [this answer](https://community.shopify.com/c/shopify-design/adding-custom-pages-to-your-domain-without-the-pages-custom-page/td-p/220443) from a Shopify Guru in 2016 that mentions potentially setting up a custom HTML template or using an app, which no longer exists.

Any clues on how to achieve this? I have limited experience with Shopify templates, but could figure it out if someone could point me in the right direction.

[This blogger](https://paulnrogers.com/shopify-url-structure/) says it can't be done:

> "Q: Can you create pages on the root? A: The answer to this is no –> all pages have either /pages/, /collections/ or /products/ in the URL."

However others have told me it is possible. Just not how to do it.

Comment: In the default Shopify store you can't update or change the URL structure, but if you using the headless Ecommerce with Shopify then you choose whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Create a section Name "test" // first a step
Create a page json Name  "test"  // The second step
After creating the page, JSON does a section test

Answer (score -1):

Bottom line is you're absolutely stuck with either /pages/, /collections/ or /products/ in the URL - no way round it, and a very good reason not to use Shopify